# Mysqli bind_param not setting but still executing

Tags: php, mysqli

I've tried many different ways of formatting this and none of them have worked.

Mysql history shows this is what it tries to execute: `SELECT * FROM operations WHERE id= ? ORDER BY exectime`

Heres the script:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM operations WHERE id = ? ORDER BY exectime";
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
  $stmt -> bind_param("i", $_SESSION["id"]);
  if($result = $stmt->execute()){
      if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
          echo $row[0];
        }
      } else {
        echo "Empty";
      }
  } else{
      echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
  }
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
?>
```

The even weirder thing is I'm using bind_param on the login pages and works completely fine.

It doesn't even echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";

Comment: Most likely there is another error. Please stop checking manually for errors. Remove all these `if` statements checks and enable automatic error reporting. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: Yea its reporting a whole lotta nothin.

Comment: Yep, i got all the error reporting. Gives me nothing.

Comment: Oh, i have I've been trying to get this to work for 2 hours.

It all executes up to here "if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt) > 0) {" and i think thats just not working because its properly executing the query.

Correction it does run that and it comes back true even tho it shouldnt.

Im losing my mind here.

Comment: Ok ive went over a couple more times.

And assuming the query runs fine.

It stops here: ```while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {```

Comment: That makes sense. It's not a valid while loop. Did you want to fetch a single row or multiple rows?

Comment: Multiple rows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overcomplicated the whole thing. It's difficult to find exactly what went wrong because the code is too messy. Your `while` loop and the preceding `if` statement are definitely incorrect.

Just keep it simple. [Enable mysqli error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439) and then use OOP style and [`get_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) method.

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM operations WHERE id = ? ORDER BY exectime");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["id"]);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);

if ($data) {
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo $row[0];
    }
} else {
    echo "Empty";
}
```